# Creating an AnimationDrawable with images from SDcard file path

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-drawable, animationdrawable

I need to create an AnimationDrawable with images on the device SDcard, I have attempted to do so by creating a drawable from path however despite successfully creating a Drawable the addFrame() method of the AnimationDrawable rejects it anyway, is there a better approach than this?

```
String pathName = "/path/to/file/xxx.jpg";
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);

    AnimationDrawable newAnim = new AnimationDrawable();

    newAnim.addFrame(d), 500);//drawable not accepted by method
    newAnim.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_2), 500);
    newAnim.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_3), 500);
    newAnim.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_4), 500);
    newAnim.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_5), 500);
    newAnim.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_6), 500);
    newAnim.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android_7), 500);
    newAnim.setOneShot(false);

    return newAnim;
```

Comment: You have one too many parenthesis on that line.

Comment: OMG how did I miss that :/